# What is the cleanest way to validate an web site address and username that a user enters that is iOS 2.0 compatible?

Tags: iphone

i am new iphone developer,any know about this please tell me how to validate web site address and username(username don't allow space,enter key ans special characters)

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the username, you should use a `NSCharacterSet` which only contains the allowed characters and then remove everything from the string which isn't in the set. Web address validating... what is a valid web address?